# Create custom list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

```
ccode = ['#005a32', '#ddf2a7', '#bfe596', '#ffffcc']
```

I am looking to generate the following output with the above color code array. Is there anyway that I can run this a loop? For the large sized Color Code array it will be useful.

```
   df1['style'] = [
        {'fillColor': '#005a32', 'weight': 2, 'color': 'black'},
        {'fillColor': '#ddf2a7', 'weight': 2, 'color': 'black'},
        {'fillColor': '#bfe596', 'weight': 2, 'color': 'black'},
        {'fillColor': '#ffffcc', 'weight': 2, 'color': 'black'},
    ]
```

Comment: is that a list, or an array? Are you working with pandas? What exactly is going on here?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: I think it is an ordinary dictionary, although I agree that it is very weird to call it `df`.

Comment: I am trying to create linear colormap codes for choropleth mapping using folium. Thanks for the answer @WillemVanOnsem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use *list comprehension* for that:

```
df1['style'] = [
        {'fillColor': color, 'weight': 2, 'color': 'black'}
        for color in ccode
    ]
```

So we iterate over the `ccode` list and assign each value to the local variable `color`. For each of these elements, we add a `{'fillColor': color, 'weight': 2, 'color': 'black'}` to the list (note that the variable `color` is used in the dictionary).